# python, pandas: InvalidIndexError when creating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been exploring the [titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data). I am trying to create a 
`dataframe` which will have the ages of the people who survived the titanic sinking, and those who didn't, in two separate columns.

```
    train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
    test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')    
    whole = pd.concat([train, test])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'survived': whole['Age'][whole['Survived'] == 1],
                       'died': whole['Age'][whole['Survived'] == 0]})
```

But I am getting this error

> pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with
>   uniquely valued Index objects

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It runs without an error on pandas 0.20.1.

Comment: Change this : `whole = pd.concat([train, test])` to `whole = pd.concat([train, test]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @Nain Yes, it worked. Can you explain what was the problem?

Comment: @ayhan I was using pandas version `0.19.2` Upgrading to `0.20.1` did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this change in your code
`whole = pd.concat([train, test]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: we can use: `pd.concat([train, test], ignore_index=True)` instead ;)

Comment: @MaxU This works too. What happens when you set `ignore_index` to `True`?

Comment: `pd.concat` will create a new default index (`np.arange(len(concatenated_df))`) for you, so it will not need to join two existing indexes and then again drop it and create a new one...